# Are implicit transactions per batch or per session in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transaction

Imagine I am running multiple batches through management studio, separated by the GO command. I'd like to know how implicit transactions will behave - is the transaction committed on a per batch basis or once for the entire execution.

Comment: I think you are confusing implicit transactions with autocommit. Autocommit will commit each statement individually whereas a transaction started via an Implicit transaction or an explicit transaction can span batches and will not be committed until an explicit COMMIT is executed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "implicit transactions"? Do you mean that you have the session property of [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql) enabled and are using that feature? Or do you mean that you just aren't specifying `BEGIN TRANSACTION`? (i.e. creating an "explicit" transaction)?

If you are meaning the `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` feature, that simply issues the `BEGIN TRAN` and nothing more. So whether or not you are using `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` to issue the `BEGIN TRAN` or if you are doing that explicitly yourself, you are still responsible for issuing the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. And yes, Transactions can span batches, whether you are using `GO` to separate batches or executing multiple queries by hitting `F5` at different times.

In either case -- `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` set to `ON` or an explicit `BEGIN  TRAN` statement -- nothing is automatically committed. The only thing that might be automatic in these two cases is a `ROLLBACK` if you close the connection without issuing the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` first.

Without either `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` set to `ON` or an explicit `BEGIN  TRAN` statement, then each individual query is its own transaction, that is "auto-committed" and you need not worry about it. Meaning, 2 separate `INSERT` statements are two completely separate transactions.

Answer (score 4):

Implicit transactions (aka chained transaction mode) span batches; the `go` command has no effect on the status of your transaction.

See [SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql) for some examples that include transactions spanning batches (ie, spanning the `go` command).

Answer (score 1):

Neither nor. They are per statement as per SQL Standard.

Which means that a batch that runs for example in a loop does not run in one transaction, but every statement is it's own atomic transaction.